# codeigniter add multiple images to single product and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, image, codeigniter, upload

I want to add multiple images to single product and insert all pictures name to database. Right now I can upload and store only one image to the database and I still cannot find a way to upload multiple images.

I am unsure where to put my loop and what the loop should contain.

Here is my code for inserting a single image:

Controller:

```
public function coba(){

            $uploadPath = realpath('./assets/images/test/');

        chmod($uploadPath, 0777);

        $nama_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES["gambar"]["size"]);

        foreach($_FILES as $k=>$v)

            for($i = 0; $i <= $count-1; $i++) {
                $nama = $v["name"][$i];

                $config["upload_path"] = $uploadPath;
                $config["allowed_types"] = "jpg|png|jpeg";
                $config["overwrite"] = true;
                $config["remove_spaces"] = true;
                $config["max_size"] = 600;
                $config["max_width"] = 800;
                $config["max_height"] = 600;

                $this->load->library("upload", $config);

                $this->upload->do_upload("gambar[$i]");
                $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                $nama_array[] = $image_data["file_name"];
                echo $nama . "<br>";
            }

        $names = implode(",", $nama_array);
        print_r($nama_array);
        echo "<br>" . $count . "<br>";
        echo "sukses";

    }
```

view :

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

                            <?php 
                                echo form_open_multipart("admin/coba");

                                echo "<p>";
                                echo form_upload("gambar");
                                echo "</p>";

                                echo form_submit("formSubmit", "Insert Product"); 

                            ?>
</body>
</html>
```

library with resize :

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Myupload {

    public function uploadFile($field) {
        //print_r($field);
        $new_file = $field['files'];

        $othimage = array();

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/test/';

        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg';

        $config['max_size'] = '600';

        $config['max_width'] = '1024';

        $config['max_height'] = '768';

        $CI->load->library('upload', $config);

        $CI->upload->initialize($config);

        $no = count($new_file['name'])-1; 

        $file= $_FILES;

        for ($i=0; $i <= $no ; $i++)
        {
            //echo $file['files']['name'][$i]; exit;
            $_FILES['files']['name']=$file['files']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['type']= $file['files']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $file['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['error']= $file['files']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['size']= $file['files']['size'][$i];
            if ($CI->upload->do_upload('files'))
            {
                $other_images = $CI->upload->data();
                $othimage[] = $other_images['file_name'];
                $path = $other_images["full_path"];

                $config1 = array(
                        "source_image" => $path,
                        "maintain_ratio" => false,
                        "width" => 640,
                        "height" => 480
                );

                echo $path . "<br>";    
                $CI->load->library("image_lib", $config1);
                if(! $CI->image_lib->resize()){
                    echo "FAIL RESIZE";
                }

            }else{
                $error = array('error' => $CI->upload->display_errors());
                //print_r($error); exit;
            }
        }
    return $othimage;
    }

}

/* End of file Myupload.php */
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Manipulation in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/image-manipulation-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below code as a example

```
public function add() {
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'myupload'));
   //print_r($_FILES);exit;
    if ($this->input->post('btnSubmit') == 'Submit') {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required|trim');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {

            $insertData = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post("title"),
                'content' => $this->input->post("content"),
            );
            if ($portfolioId = $this->portfolio_model->add($insertData)) {
                if (isset($_FILES) && $image = $this->myupload->uploadFile($_FILES, 'portfolio')) {


                    if (isset($image['error']) && $image['error']) {
                        echo $image['error'];
                        echo "Click <a href='" . base_url() . "admin/portfolio'>here</a> to go back";
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        foreach ($image as $img) {
                            $portfolioImage[] = array(
                                'images' => $img,
                                'portfolio_id' => $portfolioId
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($portfolioId = $this->portfolio_model->add_images($portfolioImage)) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Portfolio added successfully");
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("error_message", "Portfolio was not added!!");
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('data', $this->input->post());
                }
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error_message", "Portfolio was not added!!");
                $this->session->set_flashdata('data', $this->input->post());
            }
        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', validation_errors());
        }
        redirect("admin/portfolio");
    }
}
```

and create a library named Myupload.php and paste below code
**Update code for image resize**

```
  <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Myupload {

    public function uploadFile($field, $folder) {
//        print_r($field);
        $new_file = $field['files'];

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/' . $folder . '/';

        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|gif|jpg|jpeg';

        $config['max_size'] = '100000';

        $config['max_width'] = '100000';

        $config['max_height'] = '100000';

        $CI->load->library('upload', $config);
        $CI->load->library('image_lib');
        $CI->upload->initialize($config);

        $no = count($new_file['name'])-1; 
        $file= $_FILES;
        for ($i=0; $i < $no ; $i++)
        {
            // echo $file['files']['name'][$i]; exit;
            $_FILES['files']['name']=$file['files']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['type']= $file['files']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $file['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['error']= $file['files']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['files']['size']= $file['files']['size'][$i];
            if ($CI->upload->do_upload('files'))
            {
                $other_images = $CI->upload->data();
                $othimage[] = $other_images['file_name'];
                // print_r($other_images);exit;
                //image resize
                        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                        $config['source_image'] = $other_images['file_path'].$other_images['raw_name'].$other_images['file_ext'];
                        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                        $config['width']     = 250;
                        $config['height']   = 200;

                        $CI->image_lib->clear();
                        $CI->image_lib->initialize($config);
                        $CI->image_lib->resize();
                        //image resize end

            }else{
                $error = array('error' => $CI->upload->display_errors());
                print_r($error); exit;
            }
        }
    return $othimage;
    }

}

/* End of file Myupload.php */
```

Comment: codex, is that image table is different than table "title and content" ? i have question, if i seperated image table from the rest, do i insert lot images in 1 column or 1 image for 1 column in images table ??

Comment: This is my example where i insert title and content in database and images,
if you create separate table for image then you have to maintain relation of these images with your product.

Comment: i put image resize after upload images with your code, but why is it only resizing 1 image, and the other stay the same, have any clue what's causing it ?? i put the code in your library inside the loop after the upload, i have put the code above

Comment: I have made several changes in library file for image resize , use above library :-)

Comment: omg bro codex, thank you very much, you are the master, after this i'll try insert the image name to database, if i encounter with problems, hope you can help me again *_* thanks bro !!!

Comment: codex, can you show me your model code portfolio_model->add and portfolio_model->add_images($portfolioImage), i can't make this work to insert to db.

Comment: Hi @raymondspark i used separate table for data and images as you see in 
 $portfolioImage[] = array(
                                'images' => $img,
                                'portfolio_id' => $portfolioId
                            );
i stored portfolio id in array and insert this data to portfolio_image table

Answer (score 0):

My model code

```
public function add($insertData) {
        if ($this->db->insert('portfolio', $insertData))
            return $this->db->insert_id(); //give last insert id
    }


    public function add_images($insertData) {
        if ($this->db->insert_batch('portfolio_image', $insertData)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i've got crack it with very mess code, already put here the code, hope can learn more to be like you codex, simpler and effective code is better

Answer (score 0):

i have already crack this with my own, but the code is very mess, i even hard to understand the code after it worked, need to learn more to make simpler and effective code,

this is my code :

controller :

```
$this->load->library("myupload", "form_validation");
        $this->load->model("testModel");
        $barangImage = array();
        $hitung = 0;

        if($this->input->post("formSubmit")) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("nama", "Nama", "required|trim");

            if($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $insertData = array(
                    "nama" => $this->input->post("nama")
                );
                if($id = $this->testModel->add($insertData)) {

                    print_r($id);
                    $barangImage = array(
                            "barangid" => $id["id"]
                    );

                    if(isset($_FILES) && $image = $this->myupload->uploadFile($_FILES)) {

                        if(isset($image["error"]) && $image["error"]) {
                            echo $image["error"];
                        }else {
                            foreach($image as $img) {
                                ++$hitung;
                                $barangImage[] = array(
                                        "gambar" => $img,
                                        "barangid" => $id
                                );

                            }
                            print_r($barangImage);
                        }
                    }

                    if($id = $this->testModel->add_images($barangImage, $hitung)) {
                        echo "SUCCESS !!!";
                    }else {
                        echo "FAIL INSERT IMAGES!!!";
                    }
                }else {
                    echo "FAIL INSERT DATA NAMA";
                }
            }else {
                echo "FAIL VALIDASI RUN";
            }
        }
```

Model :

```
public function add($newData){
        $this->db->insert("cobabarang", $newData);

        $nama = $newData["nama"];
        $id = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM cobabarang WHERE nama = \"$nama\"");

        return $id->row_array();
        //return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function add_images($newImage, $banyakData) {
        $id;
        $gambar = null;
        //$this->db->insert("cobagambar", $newImage);
        if(count($newImage) != 1) {
            $id = $newImage[0]["barangid"]["id"];
            $gambar = null;

            for($i = 0; $i < $banyakData; $i++){
                if($banyakData-$i == 1) {
                    $gambar .= $newImage[$i]["gambar"];
                }else {
                    $gambar .= $newImage[$i]["gambar"] . ",";
                }
            }
        }else {
            $id = $newImage["barangid"];
        }

        //$gambar = $newImage[1]["gambar"];

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO cobagambar(barangid, gambar) VALUES($id, \"$gambar\")");
    }
```